# Improve loop performance with alternative solution

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two list objects,Products and Prices ,

```
var products = GetProdusts(predicate);
var prices = GetAllProductPrices();
```

For fill Product.Prices with prices object :

```
Parallel.ForEach(products ,prod=> {

   prod.Prices= prices?.Where(pr =>pr.ProductId == prod.Id)?.ToList();
});
```

This loop take a long time.
Can anyone help me how to improve this.

**Update:**

Base on @Holger comment:

```
var priceDics = prices.GroupBy(p=>p.ProductId).ToDictionary(p=>p.Key ,p=>p.ToList());

Parallel.ForEach(products ,prod=> {

  prod.Prices= priceDics?.Where(pr =>pr.Key== prod.Id)?.SelectMany(x=>x.Value).ToList();
});
```

and now performance is very improved.

Comment: Convert one of your Collections into a dictionary and iterate over the other collection. Maybe group your prices by ProductID. You can als create a Lookup, which is a good combination of grouping and dictionary. The resulting list, you should create in advance (as empty list), and add the elements, one by one. So you can avoid this nested iteration.

Comment: This case does not warrant parallelism. The overhead will probably outweigh the benefits. You just need to use an efficient data structure ([Lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2)).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I tested both Lookup and Dictionary, for me dictionary is fastest than Lookup ,and when i use Parallel loop its took 1 min and without parallel its took +5 min.

Comment: Why not use join? You may getting result only single line, moreover you have not million data, it could be faster.

Comment: Hard to believe that using a `Lookup` without parallelism it takes 5 minutes. It shouldn't take more than a second. How many products and product-prices do you have?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I have 500 hundred thousand products with 11milion product prices.

Comment: @is_oz its not possible ,because take a long time,also ef core does not have Include filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution that uses a [`Lookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2). It should be so fast that parallelism can't make it any faster.

```
var lookup = prices.ToLookup(p => p.ProductId);
foreach (var product in products)
{
    product.Prices = lookup[product.Id]?.ToList();
}
```

There is no much calculation happening inside the loop. The `lookup[...]` getter is almost instantaneous, and what is left is allocating memory for the lists, and copying the contents of each [`Grouping`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.igrouping-2) to a new `List`, which is an highly efficient, one-CPU-instruction, operation.

---

**Update:** Performance test with 500,000 products and 11,000,000 prices:

```
class Price { public int ProductId; }
class Product { public int Id; public List<Price> Prices; }

var products = Enumerable.Range(1, 500_000)
    .Select(n => new Product() { Id = n }).ToList();
var prices = Enumerable.Range(1, 11_000_000)
    .Select(n => new Price { ProductId = n % products.Count }).ToList();

var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var lookup = prices.ToLookup(p => p.ProductId);
Console.WriteLine($"Duration Lookup: {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds:#,0} msec");
foreach (var product in products)
{
    product.Prices = lookup[product.Id]?.ToList();
}
Console.WriteLine($"Duration Total: {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds:#,0} msec");
```

Output:

> Duration Lookup: 4,051 msec
>   Duration Total: 4,695 msec

The slowest part of the process is populating the `Lookup`, which is not parallelizable. The final loop of assigning prices to products can be parallelized, but it takes less than a second.